# reference printf's first argument

Tags: c, reference, arguments, printf, posix

I know I can pass multiple values to `printf` and choose which to print in format specifiers like this:

```
printf("%2$s %1$s\n","world","hello");       // prints "hello world"
```

However, I can't access the initial argument (in this case, `"%2$s %1$s\n"`) like this (`%0$s` doesn't work). It's essential that I do so. Is there any way I can access the very first argument of `printf` inside `printf`?

Comment: Why do you need to do it within the printf?  You could use str = sprintf("%2$s %1$s\n","world","hello"); and then use str with printf and other functions.

Comment: @PhilC Well, this is just an example. I'm code golfing.

Comment: The `%n$` form of conversion specifier is a [POSIX extension](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html).

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Why would you want to recurse into the format string? As already stated: this is not standard C syntax.

Comment: And even in POSIX, the arguments (following the format) are specified to be indexed from 1.  There is no provision for referring to the format string itself as if it were among the variable arguments.

Comment: But you already know the first argument, you passed it yourself... alternatively, why not duplicate it as the last (unmatched) argument, then it would be accessible.

Comment: What you want is impossible in the realm of defined behavior. Outside of it, it might be possible on *some* platforms to craft the arguments such that `printf` would overflow onto the format string, but unfortunately for you on most platforms the stack grows downwards and the arguments are pushed last-to-first so you need to overflow backwards which is impossible.

Comment: You could always write your own variant of `printf()` to handle `%0$s`, but it might make your code golfing solutions a bit large.  Maybe you shouldn't cite code golfing as the context — it's conceivable that it might have uses in I18N/L10N contexts, though I'm still a little pressed to think of good reasons why you'd need to refer to it and want to present it in the output.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The [shortest known C quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122856/61563) could be beaten if this was possible.

Comment: I'm not convinced that adding a feature to the library simply to enable shorter quine programs would be a good use of anyone's time..

Comment: You will never beat my quine :P